# search and replace with scan

Tags: ruby

I want to search and replace some digits in a
text file and that are separated by spaces and 
merge them together

like

```
asdf asdf 1 2
3 asdf asdf asdf
2 3 asdf
```

to

```
asdf asdf 123
asdf asdf asdf
23 asdf
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work, and I am not sure how to best do the replacing in the file:

```
text = File.read("testfile.txt")
p text.scan(/([\d+\s+\d+]+)/)
```

Comment: You only mention spaces as separators, but in your example, you are concatenating the '3' after a linebreak to the previous '2'. I understood that you actually wanted to include white characters (space/tab/linebreak) as separators, but then, after conversion, why do you have the linebreak between the '3' at the beginning of the second line and the previous 'asdf' at the end of the first line?

Comment: Right, there are really two questions here. (1) Is it really intended that digit strings separated by newlines be merged? And (2) If so, in that case, what exactly should we *do* with the newline?  One would think *"delete"* but in your example you *moved* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FN = 'thefile'
result = File.read(FN).gsub /(\d)\s+(?=\d)/, '\1'
open(FN, 'w') { |io| io.write(result) }
```

Comment: @Flethuseo, I'm not certain if you really want to move newlines embedded in digit strings like your example did. My answer and sawa's both just delete embedded newlines.  If you really do need to preserve each of them let us know...

Comment: Having `\s*` rather than `\s+` will do a trivial replacement. Still right, but extra replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need `\d+`. `\d` will suffice.

```
gsub(/(\d)\s+(?=\d)/, '\1')
```

If you have oniguruma installed or are using ruby1.9,

```
gsub(/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/, '')
```

Comment: please check your regex to see if it produce correct result because I can't, at least for your first example. And it depends whether we use \d+ or \d. By using \d in your 2nd example, you are introducing `?<` and `?=` into the picture, which is also unnecessary.

Comment: @kurumi I tested them. Both work without problem. Why is using `\d` relevant to `?<` and `?=`? Using lookbehind and lookahead is better because you do not have to refer to them in the replacement string. Generally, mathcing shorter is better.

Comment: your 1st example will not work for `1 2 3 4 5` (for example).

Comment: my bad, I forgot a switch in my testing. that's why i can't get your result. everything is fine.